# Excel hangs when I use an innocuous looking formula?

Tags: excel

I have a large worksheet that I have set to manual formula calculation.

I added a few new columns today and when I clicked `Calculate Sheet` it would hang at `Calculating: 0%` forever

I did some troubleshooting with the new columns and realised it was a column of sumifs that created the issue.
                                                                                                                     The formula is

```
SUMIFS($DD$3:$DD$70000,
       $DB$3:$DB$70000,
       DB3,
       $DC$3:$DC$70000,
       DC3,
       $DE$3:$DE$70000,
       DE3)
```

(dragged down for many rows) but the strange thing is when I calculate a cell with this formula individually, it calculates correctly.  There are a lot of rows so I can't check every cell in the column individually but I don't understand how it could cause Excel to hang when I calculate the whole sheet.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Try changing the Criteria 1, 2,3 etc to a different set of cells, and then select the criteriia range 1, 2, 3 as the whole of column DD, DB etc

Comment: *'forever'* is not an accurate increment of time and 69778 formulas is a lot of calculation even for a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B). Are you looking for an alternate method? Can you supply sample data?

Comment: How many volatile functions does your worksheet incorporate? Volatile functions include NOW, TODAY, INDIRECT, OFFSET, RAND, RANDBETWEEN and some sub-functions of CELL and INFO.

Comment: Jeeped - I don't think that is the problem as before I added this new sumif column there were already a few similar columns and sheet took only 60 seconds to calculate.  I would only expect this column to add another 5-10 seconds to calculation time.  Instead, the worksheet just freezes at 0% calculated.

Comment: Henry W, I think I tried what you suggested (I changes the ranges to the whole columns and moved columns) but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Some quick tests show that 7K rows (on an otherwise blank worksheet) takes ~23 seconds, 14K rows takes ~47 seconds and 70K rows of a three condition [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) takes ~282 seconds. Times are relative to machine and calculation, events and screen updating were turned off. So there appears to be something you are not relating (a Worksheet_Change or Conditional Formatting perhaps...?). btw, a VBA sub involving variant arrays and a dictionary object takes 2¾ seconds.

Comment: Jeeped, sorry, I think you were correct all along.  I didn't expect the progress to take 10mins to get past 0% but it seems like I really underestimated the complexity of this formula and there was no issue after all.  It's working fine now, although calculation is a little slow but manageable.  Thanks